# html.beginform in .NET - the third parameter seems to be take-it-or-leave-it

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
(Html.BeginForm("Search", "YOUR CONTROLLER", null)
```

I have the above code, and it links to a Controller method annotated as a Post, yet I don't have to put

```
 (Html.BeginForm("Search", "YOUR CONTROLLER", FormMethod.Post)
```

Curious why this is, haven't quite fully wrapped by head around all the nuances of Html.BeginForm yet...

Comment: `FormMethod.Post` is the default. If you do not provide a value, it uses the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html.BeginForm processes the `method` parameter using the method `GetFormMethodString` shown below:

```
public static string GetFormMethodString(FormMethod method)
{
    switch (method)
    {
        case FormMethod.Get:
            return "get";
        case FormMethod.Post:
            return "post";
        default:
            return "post";
    }
}
```

So if no method value is supplied, then the method is defaulted to `post`.

However, it's worth me mentioning that when you specify `null` for the 3rd parameter, you're not actually setting the parameter `method` to `null` you're targeting the overload that has `RouteValueDictionary` as the third paramater, *not* the one with a `FormMethod`. This is because `method` is not a nullable parameter and `RouteValueDictionary` is an object which is nullable.

`Html.BeginForm("Search", "YOUR CONTROLLER", null)` calls overload:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
```

`Html.BeginForm("Search", "YOUR CONTROLLER", FormMethod.Post` calls overload:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, FormMethod method);
```

You can see the source to this in Github at the following link: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Web.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs

Comment: Thanks, I forgot it's open source, really helpful to see the sourcecode.  So yeah, didn't realize the constructor is overloaded, and defaults to "post" if you don't specify, now it makes perfect sense

Comment: Glad to have helped :)